# javascript validation

Tags: javascript

hi anyone can help me by giving a javascript code to validate a username textbox should not contain numbers, it must only contain a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**: `isNaN`

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('myForm'), 'submit', function() {
    var val = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    if ( isNaN(val) || val.indexOf('.') !== val.lastIndexOf('.') || val.split('.')[1].length > 2) {
        alert('myInput can only contain numbers!');
    }
});
```

**Method 2**: RegExp

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('myForm'), 'submit', function() {
    var val = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    if ( !/^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(val) || val.charAt(-1) == '.') {
        alert('myInput can only contain numbers!');
    }
});
```

**Method 3**: only allow inputting numbers

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('myInput'), 'keyup', function() {
    // replace everything except digits and a decimal place on every keypress
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
});
```

Please note that users may disable JavaScript, so you should also handle invalid form values on server side.

Here's my `addEvent` function I've used for cross-browser event handling, because IE < 9 only supports `attachEvent`, and other browsers only support `addEventListener`.

```
function addEvent(element, eventType, eventHandler) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventType, eventHandler, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent('on'+eventType, eventHandler);
    }
}
```

**Update**: now only two digits are allowed after a decimal place.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using isNAN function in javascript.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex:

```
(\d)+
```

If you've got a match, you've got a number in your string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(!/\d*/.test(userName)) 
{
  //do something.. 
}
```